# Обновление и добавление данных в Sql из datagrid

Tags: sql, wpf, datagrid

Использую WPF.
Есть ли какая-то возможность обновлять и добавлять данные в MsSQL базу напрямую из DataGrid. Например DataGrid заполняется из определенной таблицы, пользователь редактирует какую-то строку, в результате нужно обновить данные в БД именно по этой строке. 
Так же и с добавлением строки, если пользователь добавил строку в Datagrid, то она добавляется и в таблице базы данных.

Comment: Нашел интересное событие DataGrid.RowEditEnding(), я так понимаю это больше подходит для редактирования. Можно ли это использовать для добавления, если да то как?

Возможно есть какие-то другие пути решения данной задачи, если есть то какие?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону DataTable + DataAdapter. Но вообще это плохой подход и не подойдет для чуть более чем самых простых приложений